# Conver text string "ABCYYYYMM" to date format in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame where dates are represented by the string "ABC202003" with the format "ABCYYYYMM". How can I remove the "ABC" part and conver it to Date format month-year in R?

Comment: Is it *always* `"ABC"`? Oh, there is no month number 20... Did you mean `"ABC022003"`?

Comment: It's YYYYMM, so the example was month 03 year 2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the digits with `parse_number` and then use `ymd` with `truncated` to convert to `Date` class.  If needed to change the format to month-Year, then use `format`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
   mutate(date = format(ymd(readr::parse_number(str), truncated = 2), '%m-%Y'))
#        str    date
#1 ABC202003 03-2020
#2 DEF202004 04-2020
```

if it needs to be `Date` class, remove the `format`

```
df %>% 
       mutate(date = ymd(readr::parse_number(str), truncated = 2))
#        str       date
#1 ABC202003 2020-03-01
#2 DEF202004 2020-04-01
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(str = c("ABC202003", "DEF202004")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked well for me. However, the resulting "date" column is a "chr" class. I am trying to convert it using as.Date(df$date, format="%m-%Y") but I am getting NAs as a result. Do you now how to conver it?

Comment: @rmae19 if you need the Date class, then just remove the `format` wrapping

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(stringr)
> str <- c('ABC202003','DEF202004')
> df <- data.frame(str = str)
> df
        str
1 ABC202003
2 DEF202004
> df %>% mutate(date = str_extract_all(str, '\\d+')) %>% 
+   mutate(date = str_replace_all(date, '(\\d{4})(\\d{2})','\\1-\\2'))
        str    date
1 ABC202003 2020-03
2 DEF202004 2020-04
>
```

In month-year format:

```
> df %>% mutate(date = str_extract_all(str, '\\d+')) %>% 
+   mutate(date = str_replace_all(date, '(\\d{4})(\\d{2})','\\2-\\1'))
        str    date
1 ABC202003 03-2020
2 DEF202004 04-2020
>
```

Answer (score 1):

The data in the question, corrected.

```
x <- "ABC022003"
```

If there are always 3 characters at the beginning of the string, first run this:

```
date <- as.Date(paste0("01", substring(x, 4)), "%d%m%Y")
```

If there could be a different number of non-numeric digits, run this:

```
date <- as.Date(paste0("01", gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", x)), "%d%m%Y")
```

Now `date` is an object of class `"character"`. Any of the following will create a month-year string.

```
format(date, "%m-%Y")
#[1] "02-2003"
format(date, "%b-%Y")
#[1] "Feb-2003"
zoo::as.yearmon(date)
#[1] "Feb 2003"
```

Answer (score 0):

First get rid of the letters at the beginning using `gsub`

```
x <- c('ABC202003','DEF202004')
x <- gsub("[^0-9.-]", "", x)
```

Then use `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` to parse it as a date

```
x <- lubridate::parse_date_time(x, orders = 'ym', truncated = 1)
```

then finally use `format` to format them as you wish

```
format(x, '%Y-%m')
```

This is the end result:

```
[1] "2020-03" "2020-04"
```